# pandas.core.base.SpecificationError - Resample

Tags: python, aggregate, timedelta, pandas-resample, back-testing

Code:

```
from __future__ import(absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals)

import backtrader as bt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np
import math

csvframe = pd.read_csv("ICICIBANK.csv", parse_dates = ["YYYYMMDD"])

print(csvframe.head())

csvframe = csvframe.set_index("YYYYMMDD")
csvframe.dropna(inplace=True)
csvframe = csvframe.resample('1M').agg({'OPEN':'first','HIGH':'max','LOW':'min','CLOSE':'last','VOLUME':'sum'})
print(csvframe.head())
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> csvframe = csvframe.resample('1M').agg({'OPEN':'first','HIGH':'max','LOW':'min','CLOSE':'last','VOLUME':'sum'})
> File "C:\Users\91994\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 298, in aggregate
> result, how = aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\91994\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py", line 582, in aggregate
> return agg_dict_like(obj, arg, _axis), True
> File "C:\Users\91994\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py", line 758, in agg_dict_like
> raise SpecificationError(f"Column(s) {cols} do not exist")
> pandas.core.base.SpecificationError: Column(s) ['HIGH', 'LOW', 'OPEN', 'VOLUME'] do not exist

Data format:
[image]

I see all columns present in my input.. I'm not sure why am getting this error.
Any suggestion please..

Comment: Is it possible your columns have trailing/leading spaces that aren't immediately obvoius? What does `print(csvframe.columns)` show you?

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be the reason. I changed the column name and then issue got fixed.